# Why do I have this error when install my game (made by unity 2019)?

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, mobile

I am a game developer and when I made a game by unity so I have a error when I installing in android phone... This is my error while installing:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GcLkr.jpg)

How do I fix this problem?
please help me
thanks

Answer (score 0):

It would seem googling holds much of the answer:

> There are three options to get rid of this warning:
>
> You need to disable Play Protect in Play Store -> Play Protect -> Settings Icon -> Scan Device for security threats.
>
> Publish app at Google Play Store.
>
> Submit an Appeal to the Play Protect.